# How to parse the email message and extract data from that message using Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to parse an email message and want to extract the data from that email using Python, can anyone suggest the code to achieve that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can import the ***email*** and ***email.policy*** using

```
import email

import email.policy
```

and then use this statement

```
email.parser.BytesParser(policy=email.policy.default).parse(f)
```

where f is the email file directory.

Comment: Could you please tell if it's possible to parse an email body directly instead of from a file? I had Microsoft Outlook `.pst` files initially. I parsed them using `pypff` library and converted them to a `csv` file. The `csv` file has columns like `deliverytime`,`subject`, `body`, etc. I need to be able to process that email body and get information out of it like removing signatures or greetings or splitting original message part and reply/forward part. If you had done anything like this, it would be a great help. Thanks.